# Is there a way to configure ejabberd to forward messages to every online client, regardless of priority?

Tags: ejabberd, xmpp

Is it possible to configure `ejabberd` to forward messages to every online instance of, say, user `joe` and not just the one with the highest priority value?

I'll also appreciate references to the XMPP standard with pointers how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the reason why this hasn't been covered by anybody because a initial google turns up absolutely nothing..

Slightly more advanced goggle-fu shows that when the priority of all resources of a given user are the same then the message will be multicast to all available resources https://www.ejabberd.im/node/4994

I could also find someone who put together a modified ejabberd which multicast to all resources (regardless of priority) https://www.ejabberd.im/node/5233

So this is possible, but may require a bit of hacking of the source ( the simplest option would be to simply force priority 1 for all sessions. )

Answer (score 1):

The official solution is for clients to declare support for [message carbons](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html). This is the modern way of delivering, which supports multiple devices.

Comment: Thanks, of course this XEP is considerably newer than my question, but still valuable to have that answer here for future reference.